# Storing a PDF generated 'on the fly' for iPad on IOS6.1

Tags: xcode, ipad, pdf

I am trying to create a PDF report from an iPad app using xcode 4.6. I know a valid pdf file is being created when run on the simulator, because I can dig it out and preview it. The commented out code does this. The problem is that I can't write it somewhere I can get at it on the iPad.

I've tried using UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData instead and trying to write the image out to the PhotoAlbum instead. The problem here is that when I convert the NSMutableData into an image it returns nil.

Here is the code. Thanks for any help you can give me.

```
- (IBAction)makePDF:(UIButton *)sender
{
    CFAttributedStringRef currentText = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, (CFStringRef)self.labelCopyright.text, NULL);

    if (currentText)
    {
        CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(currentText);
        if (framesetter)
        {
//            NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, //NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
//            NSString *pdfPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Nick.pdf"];
//            NSLog(@"pdf is at %@",pdfPath);
//            UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfPath, CGRectZero, nil);
            NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:100000];
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data, CGRectZero, nil);
            CFRange currentRange = CFRangeMake(0, 0);
            NSInteger currentPage = 0;
            BOOL done = NO;

            do
            {
                UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792), nil);
                currentPage++;
//                [self drawPageNumber:currentPage];

                currentRange = [self renderPage:currentPage withTextRange:currentRange andFramesetter:framesetter];               
                if (currentRange.location == CFAttributedStringGetLength((CFAttributedStringRef)currentText)) done = YES;
            }
            while (!done);
            UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
            UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            assert(image);
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, nil, nil);
            CFRelease(framesetter);
        }
        else NSLog(@"Could not create the framesetter needed to lay out the atrributed string.");
        CFRelease(currentText);
    }
    else NSLog(@"Could not create the attributed string for the framesetter");
}

- (CFRange)renderPage:(NSInteger)pageNum withTextRange:(CFRange)currentRange andFramesetter:(CTFramesetterRef)framesetter
{
    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(currentContext, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
    CGRect frameRect = CGRectMake(72, 72, 468, 648);
    CGMutablePathRef framePath = CGPathCreateMutable();

    CGPathAddRect(framePath, NULL, frameRect);
    CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, currentRange, framePath, NULL);

    CGPathRelease(framePath);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, 792);
    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CTFrameDraw(frameRef, currentContext);
    currentRange = CTFrameGetVisibleStringRange(frameRef);
    currentRange.location += currentRange.length;
    currentRange.length = 0;
    CFRelease(frameRef);

    return currentRange;
}
```

Comment: Ok, an update of sorts. It seems that UIMage doesn't support PDFs, so that explains the failure to transform in the ante-penultimate line of my example code. I'd still like to create a pdf that could be taken off the iPad and used elsewhere, without having to involve any server-side stuff if poss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the mutable data to your documents directory

`[data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]`

Here's an example:

```
+(void) saveData: (NSData*) data ToFileName: (NSString*) filename {

    // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: filename];

    // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
    [data writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
    //NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);
}
```

As for displaying the generated PDF on the device, the `UIWebView` object supports loading PDF files from `NSData`. Here is an example:

```
[self.webView loadData:pdfData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

It is possible to attach an `NSData` object to an email as well. Here is an example:

```
//Check if we can send e-mails
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

    //Create the Email view controller
    MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    //Set the subject and body
    [controller setSubject:@"Email Subject"];
    [controller setMessageBody:@"Email body" isHTML:NO];

    //Set the email address
    [controller setToRecipients:@"test@test.com"];

    //Add the current PDF as an attachment
    NSString *fileName = @"file.pdf";

    [controller addAttachmentData:self.retrievedPDF mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:fileName];

    // show the email controller modally
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the PDF to an `NSMutableData` object, write it to a file using `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile`.

The first argument is the file path. The best place would be the `Documents` directory. There are then many different ways to get the file out of the app:

1. iTunes file sharing
2. Email
3. iCloud
4. Sending to a 3rd party server (Dropbox, Box, Google Drive, etc.)
5. Open in another iOS app using `UIDocumentInteractionController`.